# What are common solvent removal methods?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, solvents

In a laboratory setting, the most common solvent removal method is rotary vacuum distillation. This is something I have performed many times, starting in organic chemistry labs. However, I am interested in learning of other solvent removal techniques.

Specifically, I am having a lot of trouble removing trace levels of solvent (chloroform, heptane, toluene, cyclohexane) from nicotine, which is an oil in its pure form. I have been using a rotary vacuum system to remove the solvent, though traces of solvent always remain. Nicotine is heat sensitive and degrades easily in air. Are there any other methods I should consider?

Comment: Freeze-drying is usually an excellent option, but nicotine has a very low melting point, so that's probably not feasible. Stirring the oil under high vacuum (<1 mbar)  for a few hours could work, and you might be able to afford heating it mildly (60-80 °C) in the absence of oxygen.